# numpy vectorization of interdependent arrays

Tags: numpy, vectorization

I need to populate two interdependent arrays simultaneously, based on their previous element, like so:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros(100)
b = np.zeros(100)
c = np.random.random(100)

for num in range(1, len(a)):
    a[num] = b[num-1] + c[num]
    b[num] = b[num-1] + a[num]
```

Is there a way to truly vectorize this (i.e. not using numpy.vectorize) using numpy? Note that these are arbitrary arrays, not looking for a solution for these specific values.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to do this for these specific values of `a`, `b` and `c`, or is it for arbitrary values of `c`?

Comment: @Praveen, arbitrary values for all the arrays mentioned, I'm just looking for a generic solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in @Praveen's post, we can write those expressions for few iterations trying to find the closed form and that would be a triangular matrix of course for `c`. Then, we just need to add in *iteratively-scaled* `b[0]` to get full `b`. To get `a`, we simply add shifted versions of `b` and `c`.

So, implementation-wise here's a different take on it using some [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [`dot-product`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) for efficiency purposes -

```
p = 2**np.arange(a.size-1)
scale1 = p[:,None]//p
b_out = np.append(b[0],scale1.dot(c[1:]) + 2*p*b[0])
a_out = np.append(a[0],b_out[:-1] + c[1:])
```

If `a` and `b` are meant to be always start as `0`, the code for the last two steps would simplify to -

```
b_out = np.append(0,scale1.dot(c[1:]))
a_out = np.append(0,b_out[:-1] + c[1:])
```

Comment: Thank you @Divakar!

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is:

```
c = np.arange(100)
a = 2 ** c - 1
b = numpy.cumsum(a)
```

Comment: Thank you @Nils, I was looking for a generic solution to the problem rather than for specific values of `c`, I updated my question.

Comment: A solution to your problem should be possible along the lines posted by Nils here; though I havnt checked if this is it exactly.

Comment: Thank you @Eelco, I'm having trouble understanding how this could be adapted to a non-analytical case. If `c` is populated with random numbers (see my updated question), the second line in @Nils solution cannot be replaced with an analogous vectorization, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, the updates are:

```
a_i = b_i-1 + c_i
b_i = 2*b_i-1 + c_i
```

Writing out the recursion,

```
b_0 = c_0              # I'm not sure if c_0 is to be used
b_1 = 2*b_0 + c_1
    = 2*c_0 + c_1
b_2 = 2*b_1 + c_2
    = 2*(2*c_0 + c_1) + c_2
    = 4*c_0 + 2*c_1 + c_2
b_3 = 2*b_2 + c_3
    = 2*(4*c_0 + 2*c_1 + c_2) + c_3
    = 8*c_0 + 4*c_1 + 2*c_2 + c_3
```

So it would seem that

```
b_i = np.sum((2**np.arange(i+1))[::-1] * c[:i])
a_i = b_i-1 + c_i
```

It's not possible to do a cumulative sum here, because the coefficient of `c_i` keeps changing.

The easiest way to fully vectorize this is to probably just use a giant matrix. If `c` has size `N`:

```
t = np.zeros((N, N))
x, y = np.tril_indices(N)
t[x, y] = 2 ** (x - y)
```

This gives us:

```
>>> t
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 4.,  2.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 8.,  4.,  2.,  1.]])
```

So now you can do:

```
b = np.sum(t * c, axis=1)
a = np.zeros(N)
a[1:] = b[:-1] + c[1:]
```

I probably wouldn't recommend this solution. From what little I know of computational methods, this doesn't seem numerically stable for large `N`. But I have the feeling that this would be true of any vectorized solution which performs the summation at the end. Maybe you should try both the for-loop and this piece of code out and see if your errors keep blowing up with the vectorized solution.

Comment: Thank you @Praveen! Tried to replicate the results, but `a` and `b` differ from the results given by the loop. Still, great explanation on how to get there.